# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters while check in if condition

Tags: java, selenium, if-statement

I am writing a if condition to find the element location in my project.

```
    if (!(driver.findElement(MobileBy.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("searchTextBox_XPATH"))).isDisplayed()
            || driver.findElement(MobileBy.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("routeOverview_XPATH"))).isDisplayed()
            || driver.findElement(MobileBy.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("scrollNavigationDrawer_XPATH")))
                    .isDisplayed())) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("This is not Destination Input page");
    }
```

In this code if one of the condition become true then also "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters." trigger and testcases failed.

Answer (score 0):

That is an expected behavior.

See if the element is not found then Selenium will throw

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:

so `.isDisplayed()` does not really mean anything if the element itself has not been found in HTML DOM.

because `.isDisplayed()` is meant to look for whether the element is

```
"""Whether the element is visible to a user."""
```

so when the element, any locator that you have used, is not available Selenium will throw `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:`, before calling `.isDisplayed()`

### Solution :

Now talking about the solution, I would recommend you to wrap this code inside a try and catch body.

**Code :**

```
try {
    if (!(driver.findElement(MobileBy.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("searchTextBox_XPATH"))).isDisplayed()
            || driver.findElement(MobileBy.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("routeOverview_XPATH"))).isDisplayed()
            || driver.findElement(MobileBy.xpath(ObjRepoProp.getProperty("scrollNavigationDrawer_XPATH")))
            .isDisplayed())) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("This is not Destination Input page");
    }
}
catch (NoSuchElementException ne) {
    System.out.println("In catch block to handle no such element");
    ne.printStackTrace();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("In catch block to handle Generic exception");
    Exception e.printStackTrace();
}
```

if you still see issues, you can try to use `findElements` and check the size of it in if block.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first understand how this is working.

There are 2 things happening with your code.

1. You are trying to locate an element on the webpage
2. Once you have the element then you are verifying if it is visible or not.

So if all the elements are located and found on the page, then only it will work or else you will always get `NoSuchElementException`.